# Does anyone know of a program that can search database objects (i.e. StoredProcedures) for keywords?

Tags: search, sql-server

Is there a tool that would look through a group of stored procedures for source code keywords?

A client has a lot of business logic coded into their database and I need to find where it is using certain strings of text? I.E. what procedure contains 'was applied to their balance', so I can refactor that out into business logic. Does anyone know of such a tool? Perhaps something from Red-Gate?

Answer (score 1):

Similar question has been answered earlier. You wouldn't need a 'tool' to search for text in the DB objects. A simple SQL script would suffice. Check this out for details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674623/how-to-find-a-text-inside-sql-server-procedures-triggers